# key() function within <key> element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In a key element, it is an error for the value of either the `use` attribute or the `match` attribute to contain a variable reference.

But can the `use` attribute or the `match` attribute contain a `key()` function?

This seems allowed, but it would only make sense if `key` elements are executed in document order in the stylesheet. Is that guaranteed?

(If this does indeed work, then one could sometimes use a `key()` function within a `use` or `match` to do the job that a disallowed global variable would do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But can the `use` attribute or the `match` attribute contain a key()
>   function?

**In XSLT 1.0 both of these are errors**.

From the **[W3C Errata to the XSLT 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/1999/11/REC-xslt-19991116-errata/)**:

> E13 - Substantive.
>
> Section 12.2, eighth paragraph. Calls to the key function in match and
>   use attributes on xsl:key elements may cause cycles. See
>   http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Member/w3c-xsl-wg/2000Jun/0048.html
>   (members only).
>
> It is an error for the value of either the use attribute or the match
>   attribute to contain a VariableReference, or a call to the key
>   function

In XSLT 2.0 the use of the `key()` function in these places is allowed, provided that a key is not defined in terms of itself (no circular references in definitions are allowed).

Comment: For XSLT 2.0 use of the key() function is allowed subject to the restriction that a key must not be defined in terms of itself, as explained in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#circularity

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes, of course. Any circular definition is an error.